# How to connect to a MySQL server in a Qt application

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5

I need to connect to a MySQL server in a Qt application, so I wrote the following code:

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("xxx");
    db.setUserName("xxx");
    db.setPassword("xxx");
    db.setDatabaseName("xxx");
    db.open();
```

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to run this code right from the Qt Creator it gives me the following error right after the `addDatabase` function call:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

I tried to print the last error code:

```
qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
```

Output

```
"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
```

Of course, I have a MySQL server installed on the same computer.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have some things that you have to check. Check these posts, maybe they help you.

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55365-QSqlDatabase-QMYSQL-driver-not-loaded-but-available

[QMYSQL driver available but not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667768/qmysql-driver-available-but-not-loaded)

Comment: I already saw them. Unfortunately, I don't have libmysqlclient.dll, only its static version (.lib file). I also tried to copy the whole `sqldrivers` directory to the `debug` folder and it didn't help

Comment: And do you have the qmyssql.dll?

Comment: Yes, in the sqldrivers directory

Comment: I think the problem is because you don´t have the `libmysql.dll`. Think that sometimes a .lib file is only a 'bridge' between the application and the .dll. Check this, maybe you don´t have seen before http://seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows

Comment: I already put libmysql.dll near the executable file and in the sqldrivers directory

Comment: And have you rebuilt your app?

Comment: Why should I rebuild an app after putting a .dll file? But yes, I already tried it

Comment: Ok, at this point I am also stuck. But the problem is with the `libmysql.dll` for sure, because Qt can find the mysql driver (`qmyssql.dll`). But I really don´t know what is going on. May be you need to recompile Qt against the right libraries, but I´m not sure. Sorry.