# Ubuntu Pyqt QMYSQL driver available but not loaded

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

[image]

How do I load qmysql driver in Ubuntu PyQt? I have the following code that produces these results:

("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3") 
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYS

Comment: install this: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev libqt5sql5-mysql`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMYSQL driver available but not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667768/qmysql-driver-available-but-not-loaded)

Comment: @eyllanescl  I installed  libmysqlclient-dev libqt5sql5-mysql not possible.

Comment: Find the appropriate package name with: `sudo apt-cache search libmysqlclient` and `sudo apt-cache search libqt5sql5`

Comment: @eylianesc libmysqlclient-dev - MySQL database development files
libmysqlclient20 - MySQL database client library
libcrypt-mysql-perl - Perl module to emulate the MySQL PASSWORD() function
libglpk36 - linear programming kit with integer (MIP) support

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: @eyllanesc  libmysqlclient-dev Installed

Comment: execute this: `sudo apt-cache search libqt5sql5`

Comment: @eyllabesc libqt5sql5 - Qt 5 SQL module
libqt5sql5-sqlite - Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
libqt5sql5-mysql - Qt 5 MySQL database driver
libqt5sql5-odbc - Qt 5 ODBC database driver
libqt5sql5-psql - Qt 5 PostgreSQL database driver
libqt5sql5-tds - Qt 5 FreeTDS database driver

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5sql5-mysql libqt5sql5-odbc  libqt5sql5-psql libqt5sql5-tds  libqt5sql5`

Comment: Install all the packages that come out on that list.

Comment: Installed pycharm QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Comment: Find the `libqsqlmysql.so` file and run: `ldd libqsqlmysql.so`

Comment: @eyllanesc libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found

Comment: An easy way to find it is to run: `sudo locate libqsqlmysql.so`

Comment: ldd libqsqlmysql.so libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found

Comment: @eyllanesc              
/home/pos/Development/DB_Change/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so

Comment: execute: `ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/sqldrivers/libq‌​sqlmysql.so`

Comment: @eyllanesc There is no such file.

Comment: execute: `sudo updatedb && sudo locate libqsqlmysql.so`

Comment: /home/pos/Development/DB_Change/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so

Comment: execute: `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysq‌​l.so`

Comment: And also try to reinstall pyqt5.

Comment: There is no such file.

Comment: I find it strange, try restarting your pc.

Comment: libqsqlmysq‌​‌​l.so no surch

Comment: execute this: `sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5`

Comment: @eyllanesc libqt5sql5 Installed

Comment: execute: `locate libqsqlmysql.so`

Comment: /home/pos/Development/DB_Change/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so

Comment: @eyllanesc Computer Restart is Pyqt Reinstall

Comment: QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Comment: execute: `cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/` and then run: `ldd libqsqlmysql.‌​so`

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff69bee000)
 libmysqlclient.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20 (0x00007f218151f000)
 libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f21814dd000)
 libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f2181006000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2180c84000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f21808bb000)

Comment: libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2180c84000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f21808bb000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f21806a0000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f218049c000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f218027f000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f217ff75000)

Comment: ibgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f217fd5f000)
 libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f217f8fd000)
 libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f217f568000)
 libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x00007f217f302000)
 libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f217eff1000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f217ede8000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000564ec1cdb000)

Comment: @eyllanesc I can not run QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Comment: How have you installed pyqt?

Comment: @eyllanesc /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers$ ldd libqsqlmysql.so 
libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-cache search libmysqlclient`

Comment: @eyllanesc  Pycharm settings install pyqt5

Comment: ibmysqlclient-dev - MySQL database development files
libmysqlclient20 - MySQL database client library
libcrypt-mysql-perl - Perl module to emulate the MySQL PASSWORD() function
libglpk36 - linear programming kit with integer (MIP) support

Comment: Do not install it through pycharm, uninstall it and run: sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5

Comment: Pycharm can generate errors since the version you install may be incompatible with your OS.

Comment: @eyllanesc'll restart it.

Comment: @eyllanesc
The following packages are no longer automatically installed.

Comment: Have you uninstalled pyqt5?

Comment: pychamr is uninstall pyqt5 Package list not pyqt

Comment: Execute: File >> Settings >> Project: your_project >> Project Interpreter and look for the package pyqt or pyqt5 or the one you have installed and uninstalled.

Comment: @eyllanesc sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5  It is installed. Pycharm is pyqt Uninstalled

Comment: Still the problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc 
On Linux, there is pyqt. Pycharm says there are no packages.

Comment: Restart pycharm, then pycharm scans packages

Comment: @eyllanesc  yes problem

Comment: Did you restart pycharm?

Comment: @eyllanesc restart Pyacharm no list Pyqt5

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5

Comment: You should recognize it, try to create a new project or restart your pc.

Comment: eyllanesc Thank you

Comment: it worked??????

Comment: @eyllanesc pycharm  Project Interpreter and look for the package No PyQT5

Comment: Try running your project from the console: `python3 your_script.py`

Comment: @eyllanesc python3 script.py No surch file

Comment: I think you are a beginner in linux, you have to pass the full path, goodbye

Comment: @eyllanesc thankyou