# Qt: QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, sqlite

I've just done developing a QT CRUD Application. I am using SQLite to store the information locally in my disk where the application is running. This way my application works fine.

But the app lack the the a central database server. Therefor, I started by installing MySql-server and MySql-workbench. I imported my DB in the workbench and made sure the server is running.

Now on Qt, I wrote the following lines to conenct to my server on the "localhost " using port "3306" as follow:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPort(3306);
db.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
db.setUserName(userName);
db.setPassword(userPass);

qDebug() << appDataPath;

if (!db.open()){
    return db.lastError().text();
}
```

However, I get the following error on QT "Application Outout ":

> QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded 
>   QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

I tried to make sure that `libmysql.dll` is located in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib" ..

I copied it also to  "C:\Users\Abubakr\Documents\GitHub\DEBUG\build-Muwassa-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit2-debug"

but it is not working at all.

Please help !!

Comment: Did you build Qt with mysql  support? It's not enabled by default.

Comment: Is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib` in your system path?

Comment: ***If possible, a tutorial on how to connect Qt on windows to Mysql server will help a lot*** That is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMYSQL driver available but not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667768/qmysql-driver-available-but-not-loaded)

Comment: @drescherjm : what do you mean ? I installed Qt long time ago, then installed MySql. I don't understnad how can I build Qt myself with mysql support ?! ..... and yes, the `lib` folder is stated in my system path variable.... Sorry also about asking for tutorial, I agree with yo u (I'll remove the request)

Comment: I believe the official Qt binaries do not come with support for mysql. If you want that you have to build Qt yourself.

Comment: ***I don't understnad how can I build Qt myself with mysql support*** Compile the source code of Qt. It is one of the downloads. When you configure it you enable mysql support. This is done in the shell / command line so check the arguments of configure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the QMYSQL driver by yourself first.

When you download Qt you have also the source that are provided with it.

In my case, it is in : `C:\Qt\5.9\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql`
Here you have a *.pro (that is a kind of makefile generator). You just have to open it with QtCreator, Compile it and you will get a dll. This dll is the MySQL driver and must be in the same dirent of your application.

To do that, if you have a problem with the compilation (like mysql.h not found), you must "install" mysql library also.

In Linux you can have the same issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's late to answer, but this may be useful for future readers.

When QMYSQL is available but not loaded, you should find `libqsqlmysql.a` and `libqsqlmysqld.a` files corresponding to `qsqlmysql.dll` and `qsqlmysqld.dll` files and copy them (.a files) into the `\mingw73_xx\lib` folder. (replace `xx` by 64 or 32)

Note that for project kit 64 bit use MySql 64 bit, and for project kit 32 bit use MySql 32 bit.

Details are available at [QT : QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded [WINDOWS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973048/qt-qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-windows/67642478#67642478)